# Перевод ленточной матрицы в обычную

Tags: c#, .net

Необходимо трансформировать ленточные (что  это такое можно посмотреть [тут](http://num-anal.srcc.msu.ru/lib_na/org/org_matr.htm)) матрицы в обычные. Не хочется изобретать велосипед. Может, кто знает библиотеки/алгоритмы, позволяющие делать такое преобразование?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Какой велосипед? Там кода на пару строчек.

Вот, набросал на коленке преобразование в ленточную форму и обратно:

```
using static System.Console;

static void Main ()
{
    const int N = 5;
    const int KL = 2, KU = 1, B = KL + KU + 1;

    var a = new int[N, N] {
        { 11, 12, 00, 00, 00 },
        { 21, 22, 23, 00, 00 },
        { 31, 32, 33, 34, 00 },
        { 00, 42, 43, 44, 45 },
        { 00, 00, 53, 54, 55 }
    };

    var b = new int[N, B];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < B; j++) {
            int y = i + j - KL;
            b[i, j] = y >= 0 && y < N ? a[i, y] : 0;
        }
    }

    var c = new int[N, N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            int y = j - i + KL;
            c[i, j] = y >= 0 && y < B ? b[i, y] : 0;
        }
    }

    Print(a);
    Print(b);
    Print(c);
    ReadKey();
}

static void Print (int[,] m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m.GetLength(0); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.GetLength(1); j++)
            Write("{0:00} ", m[i, j]);
        WriteLine();
    }
    WriteLine();
}
```

Вывод:

```
11 12 00 00 00
21 22 23 00 00
31 32 33 34 00
00 42 43 44 45
00 00 53 54 55

00 00 11 12
00 21 22 23
31 32 33 34
42 43 44 45
53 54 55 00

11 12 00 00 00
21 22 23 00 00
31 32 33 34 00
00 42 43 44 45
00 00 53 54 55
```

Отсутствие багов не гарантирую. :) Но на примере из статьи преобразование работает, так что вам остаётся только проверить, что всё правильно работает во всех случаях.

Comment: большое спасибо, чуть позже протестирую ваше решение.  З.Ы. `набросал на коленке`  `Отсутствие багов не гарантирую. :)` мне кажется это и есть неотъемлемые характеристики  велосипедов ;)

Comment: похоже, что это действительно работает, спасибо